# Apache2 "localhost" works but for 127.0.0.1 I get "This site can’t be reached refused to connect". SSL also returns authorization error

Tags: docker, apache, ssl, openssl, vhosts

I am trying to run an apache2 under docker (WSL2) with a self-signing certification to test SSL. The docker file script looks like this

```
FROM php:7.1-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev
COPY ./certs/* /etc/apache2/ssl/
COPY dev.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.conf
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip mbstring
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN service apache2 restart
```

with `dev.conf` containing the SSL virtual host shown below.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
    SSLEngine on
    
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/server.key" 
                
    ServerName dev-asusrog.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Running at port 80 using chrome/firefox/opera at `http://localhost:80` it works. The same, but using `http://127.0.0.1:80` instead, I get "This site can’t be reached" refused to connect."  IP6 only version protocol is disabled.

```
sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only
net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0
```

Using `curl -v localhost` or `curl -v 127.0.0.1` seems to work in both cases.

```
curl -v localhost
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 08:39:23 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
< Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 08:05:26 GMT
< ETag: "20-5b8af7c33cb30"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 32
< Content-Type: text/html
<
<html>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact


curl -v 127.0.0.1
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 08:39:33 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
< Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 08:05:26 GMT
< ETag: "20-5b8af7c33cb30"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 32
< Content-Type: text/html
<
<html>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

Running `https://dev-asusrog.com/` (I have already set under host file dev-asusrog.com point to 127.0.1.1) I get "*Access to dev-asusrog.com was denied. You don't have the authorization to view this page. HTTP ERROR 403*"

Files `server.crt` and `server.key` files are created using openssl using the command below using as server FQDN the fake server above `dev-asusrog.com`.

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt
```

I get the following Apache2 errors. The 1st one, about fully qualified domain name, is fixed by adding the `ServerName localhost` statement under `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. How about the others?

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Jan 12 11:53:39.329396 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 22] AH01906: dev-asusrog.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Jan 12 11:53:39.329797 2021] [ssl:error] [pid 22] AH02217: ssl_stapling_init_cert: can't retrieve issuer certificate! [subject: CN=dev-asusrog.com,OU=informatics,O=Company,L=mystate,ST=mystate,C=US / issuer: CN=dev-asusrog.com,OU=informatics,O=Company,L=mystate,ST=mystate,C=US / serial: 08C832686429FFF4C45180A8806FE16A278B41A3 / notbefore: Jan 11 10:40:12 2021 GMT / notafter: Jan 11 10:40:12 2022 GMT]
[Tue Jan 12 11:53:39.329830 2021] [ssl:error] [pid 22] AH02604: Unable to configure certificate dev-asusrog.com:443:0 for stapling
```

Any help here?

Comment: Can you share output of command?   netstat -nltup | grep -e 80 -e 443

Comment: @amitdahiya

`(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st step) I had to change/add under `\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` the local testing domain
from `127.0.0.1 dev-asusrog.com` to `::1 dev-asusrog.com` as Olaf Kock recommended.

2nd step) I had to disable the `SSLUseStapling` parameter under `ssl-params.conf` ie commented out

```
#SSLUseStapling on
```

3nd -option- step) Install server.crt certification in the Windows Trusted Root Certification Authorities
For your convenience, I attach the affected files below.

My Dockerfile changed to this

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

COPY ./certs/* /etc/apache2/ssl/
COPY ssl-params.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/
COPY ./sites-available/* /etc/apache2/sites-available/
RUN a2enconf ssl-params
RUN a2ensite default-ssl
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN a2enmod headers

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

RUN service apache2 restart
```

My `ssl-params.conf` is declared like this

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACH$
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

SSLHonorCipherOrder On

# Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
# the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
# Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains"

Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

# Requires Apache >= 2.4
SSLCompression off
#SSLUseStapling on
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"

# Requires Apache >= 2.4.11
SSLSessionTickets Off
```

The file `sites-available/default-ssl.conf` is declared like this

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin your_email@example.com
                ServerName dev-asusrog.com

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt"
                SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/server.key"             

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                               nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                               downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Hope it will help you in case you have the same problem I had.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2):

`localhost` typically is an alias to `::1` these days (note: IPV6), while `127.0.0.1` is obviously IPV4. Thus, you're connecting to different endpoints and if you don't explicitly open up IPV4 connections, there's nothing listening there.

Comment: Yes, that's true. How can I open IPv4? I thought they were opened by default. How about the SSL error?

Comment: You have two layers to locate the root cause, but the most important one in this case will be Docker: If Docker doesn't make the IPV4 address available, it doesn't matter what httpd does. With regards to the SSL error - this goes dangerously close to be a configuration rather than programming question, thus off topic on stackoverflow [help/on-topic]. You might find better help on other sites, e.g. serverfault.com

Comment: Hi, I already solved my problem. Please read my answer above. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I had the same exact issue with "Site Can't Be Reached". Changing my host configuration to ::1 <mydomain> is what fixed it for me.